# Center text on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with text hover.
When I hover the text on right side, it forces the hover to left side and creates glitching effect.

[image]

Is there a way to center the hover?

HTML

```
<div class="adress">
  <p class="copy"><span>Text Text Text</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p {
  float: left; /* Important */
}

.copy {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.adress:hover p.copy span {
    display: none;
}

.adress:hover p.copy:after {
    content: 'Copy';
    color: #fff;
    background: #80bdf7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/rtzksobr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you have given `float: left` as not to remove and important. That's what is causing it. If you really need `float: left`, then do this:

```
p {
  float: left; /* Important */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Snippet** that works.

```css
p {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.copy {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.adress:hover p.copy span {
  display: none;
}
.adress:hover p.copy:after {
  content: 'Copy';
  color: #fff;
  background: #80bdf7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adress">
  <p class="copy"><span>Text Text Text</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the float and then making the div a block with a full width to fit the page. This will allow you to then center the div on the page with text-align. If you want to center Copy in the middle of where the Span text is placed, you could maybe make the width the size of the span text which could be achieved by making the span and the p the same size width.

```css
p {
  float: left; /* Important */
}

.copy {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
        
.adress:hover p.copy span {
    display: none;
}

.adress:hover p {
  clear: left;
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;

}
        
.adress:hover p.copy:after {
    content: 'Copy';
    color: #fff;
    background: #80bdf7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adress">
  <p class="copy"><span>Text Text Text</span></p>
</div>
```